# How do I send Solana balance from command prompt to Phantom wallet?

Tags: phantom, command

im tryna send my solana balance on Command Prompt to my phantom wallet? can anyone help ?

Comment: What do you mean send the balance ? If you mean two different wallets you can use ‘solana transfer’ in the prompt to send to your Phantom wallet

Comment: do i start code by ( Solana address Recipient address amount sender address)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `solana transfer <PHANTOM_ADDRESS> <AMOUNT>` where you replace `<PHANTOM_ADDRESS>` with your coppied phantom address and `<AMOUNT>` with the amount of sol you want to send. You can also do `ALL` for the amount.

Comment: i know it was a noobie question but ive been searching up videos for hours